# Cannot run config.sh on server that is running Jira

Tags: java, tomcat

I installed Jira on a Centos 7 VM. Jira is already running and it seems to be working well.  I am trying to configure it to run through https. When I try to run config.sh I get an error that java is running the wrong JVM version.

```
[root@server02 bin]# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.71-2.b15.el7_2.x86_64/jre
[root@server02 bin]# ./config.sh
*************************************************************************************************************************************
**********     Wrong JVM version! You are running with .. but JIRA requires at least 1.8 to run.      **********
*************************************************************************************************************************************
[root@server02 bin]# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_71"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_71-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.71-b15, mixed mode)
```

After remove OpenJDK and install Oracle JDK

```
[root@server02 bin]# ./check-java.sh
*************************************************************************************************************************************
**********     Wrong JVM version! You are running with .. but JIRA requires at least 1.8 to run.      **********
*************************************************************************************************************************************
[root@server02 bin]# javac -version
javac 1.8.0_60
[root@server02 bin]# java -version
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

Comment: what is the script checking exactly when it's doing the version check?

Comment: This script is checking the java version on this machine first ,after that if the version is compatible ,it lets you configure Jira .

Comment: First of all when i tryed to run this script ,it was another error : "No JRE_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable is set - attempting to just run java command" and " Wrong JVM version! You are running with java version "1.7.0_95" but JIRA requires at least 1.8 to run." I removed the old version and installed 1.8 , after that  i set $JAVA_HOME .

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because because [OpenJDK is not supported by JIRA](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/openjdk-is-not-supported-292126762.html).

Check also the [supported platforms for JIRA](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/supported-platforms-207488170.html).

You have to install the [Oracle JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Comment: Already done .. But when i rtyed to run  ./check-java.sh
It is the same error .

Answer (score 0):

You should locate and modify "check-java.sh" from your jira installation folder.

It greps for "java version" string in "java -version" command output, however openjdk returns "openjdk version" string instead.

So, replace "java version" with "openjdk version" in check-java.sh.

Comment: How can it be not defined? It's defined explicitly in bin/config.sh:

Comment: The comment from @ARA1307 refers to my deleted comment about _RUNJAVA not being defined. Checking the script again I agree - I don't know how I got to that conclusion.